# Cut down on the [trimming]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Seems like [trimming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trimming) and [trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trim) are synonymous.  I recommend merging "trimming" into "trim", since the latter has more usage.