# Keep the love of puns [burninating] in our hearts

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

[Why do people have a little [pun] with their retag and burninate requests?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests) was asked middle of last year. The consensus was pretty clear: puns are a good way to lighten up an otherwise deadly dull subject.

However, recently there was [an edit war on a burninate request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/295233/revisions) using the [new system](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307068/make-it-easier-to-prevent-new-questions-being-added-in-a-tag/307124#307124). Apparently it was determined in chat based on some ♦ title edits that puns should no longer be permitted; the [reasons given to me](//chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28772277#28772277) had to do with professionalism now that burninate requests involve the whole community via featuring in the Community Bulletin box. This was thought to be so beyond dispute that a few users took it upon themselves to "educate" meta about this.

But I don't think *that* many more people click on featured questions than click on hot questions in the same box, and almost any decent burninate request will eventually land in hot questions for some time. So I'd like to keep around the puns to keep things interesting… not just for burnination, but for everything else that lands in CB. If there's a persistent trend of "ugh, that was boring, why did I click on that", people will start ignoring CB more.

If burninations have been able to tolerate the occasional excess around puns for years, there's no good reason to abruptly ban them just because there's a little more attention on the questions now. It might make sense to cut back on the calls for more puns on requests that are already going to be featured, but removing puns that are already there seems unnecessary, and *edit wars* about that (in *either* direction) are beyond the pale.

So let's work out whether puns are still a thing we want in tag cleanup in a separate discussion, rather than fighting about it with edits back and forth.

Comment: I think fun is great, however my suggestion would be to avoid / remove  puns in titles _only while it's featured_. [Shog seems to agree with me here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/21): "_It stops being cute and fun when someone has to handle a crapload of flags about it_".

Comment: @JonasCz: I'm hoping someone will chime in more about the flag thing, myself; I can't tell whether that was an edit war-based flag spree, or something that started before that, nor whether there's something else we can do to prevent flags.

Comment: An OP has the moral right to revert an edit and say "I prefer it this way".

Comment: @JonasCz what's up with the flags? Don't the interested parties follow the [meta-tag:burninate-request] tag rather than titles?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Yes, in general, but no one has the right to engage in edit wars. (And in really pressing cases, the OP's desire to keep a title the community at large can't stand is not likely to be upheld all that much.)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, Yes, but when it's in the "Featured on meta" in the sidebar (as it is right now), it's visible to _everyone_ even if they don't follow [burninate-request] here. New users might be getting confused when they see something with a strange title in the sidebar. I guess that's why Shog edited the title to "Should the corners tag be burninated (removed from all questions) ?” It's boring - but obvious and easy to understand for everyone.

Comment: I can share my experience with TVTropes in this regard. They invent punny names for all sorts of things in their administrative work. For me as an outsider, this is a bit irritating because 1)titles don't tell me much (if anything); 2)when I'm searching for something, I can't know how they decided to call it. But here, there are tags for these purposes. @JonasCz's concern about the sidebar is valid though as there are no tags there.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Are the trope names confusing because they're *puns*, or because they're *inside jokes*? I'd figured more the latter. Here, our puns are usually fairly accessible to anyone on SO that knows some American culture. (Puns on MSO have never had anything to do with findability that I know of.)

Comment: Users who want to save the tag are only being notified (with a featured post) for one day.  We ought to make it clear to them what's at stake.  (The current burnination request seems uncontroversial, but if the process is used for future requests, there will eventually be a controversial one.)  Before and after that, we might as well let people try to be witty.

Comment: @NathanTuggy They are puns that tend to evolve into local jargon. E.g. their bugtracker is called "BUGS BUGS BUGS in the Code Updates", place to suggest new articles "YKTTW" ("you know, the thing where..."), and to report incorrect ones - "YKTTW Crash Rescue".
I'm not telling about trope names which are _supposed_ to be fun to deal with (though for them, this is true as well; redirects with more obvious names solve this problem somewhat), I'm telling about forums where the need to find things to be able to do useful work is more prevalent.

Comment: Meh, that was just the OP disliking *any* edit to his post.  Makes you wonder why he thinks it is okay to edit a question with the [corners] tag for such a fluffy reason.

Comment: Puns in burninate requests are so 2015. Anyhow, if the OP doesn't want them I don't think we should force them on it. But in this case it was like @HansPassant, he didn't really want any edit, even the ones that actually improved it, like the "burnitiate" one.

Comment: One big downside to puns in titles is that they make the language barrier that some users face while using the site a bigger obstacle. But it's debatable whether those users could significantly contribute to meta...

Comment: It was not the OP trying to prevent the post from being edited as mentioned above. Shog himself [edited out the title](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/21) on that post. The same was done with [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/258571/4). The normal burnination requests still have the puns. Only the formalized requests are changed.

Comment: @HansPassant Less arrogance please and more research. My title had a pun and quite a lot of discussion in the comments section about puns. If you read the new burnination process you'd seen that there is a formal title for it. The editing, including rollbacks, and the *massive* comments removal was done by / with the supervising moderator (Madara) and at Shog's request.

Comment: @user1803551: He perhaps meant that a number of *your* rollbacks were just to reverse the correction of the typo thereby making it incorrect again. Like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/14), [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/18), and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/16).

Comment: @Abhitalks I had asked if the typo was deliberate in a comment below the post. The comment was deleted and the title kept. It implied that the title was not a typo. There were further comments stating something like *Thanks to the comment, else I would have fixed the typo*. The rollback started only after the comments there were deleted to keep them on-topic.

Comment: @Abhitalks As I retraced the history in my answer, it was believed at the time that it was not a typo and it was intended. The rollback were meant to keep the moderator's title.

Comment: @BhargavRao That's good to know, since there are no trace of deleted comments, I couldn't add that to the history of the post in my answer. Maybe you could comment that on it? (or even edit it in, OP agrees :D)

Comment: Ahhh.. what utter confusion!

Comment: @Tunaki I do not have the exact messages. Perhaps a mod can help with that.

Comment: You think puns in titles are bad? Wait till you see tags in titles - the unironic kind.

Comment: What the hell is this discussion about?

Comment: @JoeBlow What part are you confused about? It seems pretty obvious to me.

Comment: @JonasCz if a mod gets tired of handling flags on a post they can easily let another mod handle them.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was the puns in the titles in the sidebar that first drew my attention to the burnination process.  I find it pretty strange that several people seem to be saying that such titles are fine sometimes, but bad, bad, bad if they appear in the sidebar.  Are we *embarrassed* by our own culture?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes, and apparently, *only* if they get there by being featured. (I'd never heard any such fuss from the numerous requests that made it there by being hot.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy You have to remember that until recently _no burnination requests got featured_, and burninations were completely unregulated, most of which were undertaken by a few or even just one individual operating without any real consensus. This led to prolific contributors who actually used the tags not finding out about the burninations until _after_ a group of well meaning users had run roughshod all over said tag. This was because even if the burnination post made it to the HMQ board, it had a title that did not clearly communicate the purpose of the post. ...

Comment: ...  The whole comment removal thing was because we were ending up with requests that had upwards of 20 different suggestions for title puns, and little to no discussion about the merits of the tag. These burninations were also largely just piling up without much action being taken. So there were a lot of reasons to want to increase views by featuring, and stimulate discussion and participation by deletion of the comments.

Comment: It was important while coming up with all of this that we left the initial fun stage as it was though, so that people would actually read the requests at all in order to get the posts to the minimum score required for featuring as per the burnination procedure.

Comment: @TinyGiant: [citation-needed] on the title not communicating the purpose of the post to those interested. More likely, the users didn't see, or ignored, the hot questions, or didn't think they were urgent (because some weren't followed up on reliably). (Also, anyone who does not grasp the meaning of "Something funny and [destruct]ive" when they routinely use [destruct] is not going to understand "Burninate [destruct]" any better without frequenting meta, after which they will understand the pun titles anyway.) Finally, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4099598+[burninate-request].

Comment: I'm recalling actual complaints from actual users that prompted the change I'm describing, and the titles since then are supposed to follow the format of "Should we burninate the [name of tag] tag?" Which is absolutely clearer than any pun you could muster. Finally, I'm aware that you were involved in many burninations prior to the change, so was I. I don't see how that changes anything.

Comment: @TinyGiant: My point was that condescension to me ("You have to remember that until recently"), as though I were somehow unaware of the details of the previous process, is really unjustified. And again, unspecified generalized anecdotes of problems (which no one would doubt) doesn't do much to drill down on the actual, precise cause of the problem, or support the exact measures taken. Something had to be done about the old system, maybe, but it's not at all clear that every last detail of the new one is justified, either by being better in any way, or by being a better tradeoff overall.

Comment: @NathanTuggy My point by that statement was not to be condescending. I guess I just don't understand your stance on this stuff, because as far as I can see every change that was implemented has benefited the actual participation in and completion of burnination requests. It's like you're being nostalgic for a time that actually sucked quite a bit. We fought fairly hard to get _any_ participation from the moderation team and the community at large in burnination requests _at all_.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Most of the new process is fine. It's this one thing that I simply do not understand. Worse, I specifically asked this question *because* I didn't understand and didn't like it, and got very heavily upvoted … but those making title edits to remove puns did not appear to accept those votes, or the votes on various answers here that support leaving the puns alone, and just bulled ahead with whatever they were going to do anyway. So from my perspective, in an effort nominally to get community buy-in, they ignored the existing meta community in favor of, I dunno, a chatroom clique?

Comment: @TinyGiant: In short, there was never any serious attempt to achieve consensus on that. It was just rammed through against the protests of lots of folks that had been involved in burninations in the past, without persisting in making *convincing* arguments. You know, arguments that convince reasonable people. Presumably those making the change thought their arguments were good enough and they didn't need to listen to those that still disagreed. So coming along two years later with a random comment that starts off by talking about how shallow my understanding must be… yeah, that rubs me wrong.

Answer (score 143):

For those of you who are so concerned about being "oh, so serious" here, do note that the word "burninate" originates from a [Homestar Runner](http://www.homestarrunner.com/) vintage video game spoof featuring a dragon called [Trogdor](http://www.homestarrunner.com/trogdor.html).

[image]

I can't possibly be the only one that appreciates the irony here.

Comment: Could the *crapload of flags* Shog refers to be rejected with that picture as a reason? It would be even funnier that way.

Comment: I think it is high time we change that term to [*massternate*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/282933/4099593)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Perhaps the rejection message should just be a link to this answer?

Comment: I spent the entire time reading this topic thinking "You're talking about a process called *burnination*, and somebody wants to bring *professionalism* into this picture?" I love that the line is apparently drawn beyond the Trogdor, but puns? Oh my, no - think of how meta looks!

Comment: Is that picture real? Because I think the buildings are fake..

Comment: I don't know the source, but looks like pretty recent Old Spice advert for me =]

Comment: How can anyone consider themselves a l33t programmer if they don't know about Trogdor the Burninator?  He's just an S, with a more different S.

Comment: @CaptainHypertext So  _that's_ the giant S Jeff was referring to as his melee weapon of choice?

Comment: irony appreciated with an upvote.

Answer (score 80):

Just a general observation: jokes aren't usually funny when you try too hard. Unless the joke is that you're trying too hard to make something funny.

Right now I'm getting a lot more amusement out of this discussion than I am from the increasingly-strained attempts at humor in titles.

Maybe don't try so hard. Start *having* fun, and stop trying to force other people to sign on to your carefully-defined rule-based brand of "fun".

Oh, and stop messing with titles while they're pinned to the sidebar of every page on the site. That's just vandalism.

Comment: Feature request: Lock post title when it's featured! Seriously though, this answer is exactly how I feel. The puns were funny, but every other post with a punny title is just tedious, often to the point of them not making any sense.

Comment: @DavidG locking prevents: voting, flagging, editing, answering...

Comment: @Braiam I know, hence the FR. Might not be a bad idea either as it keeps the CB clean.

Comment: Burninate puns are not supposed to be funny. On the contrary, they should be embarrassingly lame, so that everyone hurries up with the burnination, just to make the pun go away.

Comment: I thought you were one of the good guys, Shog. Please provide me with a mailing address so I can send back my friendship bracelet

Comment: You never actually gave him a friendship bracelet, Shog... *it's a trap!*

Comment: Definitely a trap - I'm still wearing both of them, @BoltClock. *Eyes Pekka suspiciously*

Comment: Puns are *never* funny. Puns are *painful*, and it's just that some people have masochistic funny bones. That said, the proper punishment for perpetuating puns is THWACKing, not banning.

Comment: @Pekka웃: "I thought you were one of the good guys, Shog." - What bizarre planet did you come from?  Shog gets cast as the Bad Guy more often than all the other mods combined.

Comment: "**start having fun**" you heard it here first!

Comment: oops, upvoted this post before I realized it was from Shog. [A creepy disembodied head](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) should not be allowed to speak on the subject of humor.

Comment: And do remember that humour doesn't travel well. It's jokes like the word "burninate" that make the site feel so foreign to many of its users.

Answer (score 56):

I'm glad you're making a Meta post for that since it clearly needs to be agreed upon what to do with puns on [burninate-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) posts. However, the conclusion that the title "edit war" was due to the *presence* of a pun in a post title disagrees with the evidence.

---

First, I'll trace back some of the events that happened for the previous featured burninate-request of [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) and for the current burninate-request for [corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corners).

For [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once):

- The initial burninate-request for [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) was titled ["Burninate [once]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/258571/1), without any pun.
- Then, when the new burninate process took place, [the post was featured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/258571/2) and a notice was consequently added.
- The day after, the title was edited by a user to be the pun ["Not even [once]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/258571/3) (so the title stayed unchanged for practically 1 year).
- Shog9 quickly re-edited the title to be ["Should we burninate the tag [once]?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/258571/4).
- Then, the post was status-planned and status-completed when the tag was finally gone.

For [corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corners), the events are quite different:

- The initial burninate-request was titled with the pun ["Should we throw the [corners] in the corner?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/1).
- Then, the post [was featured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/9) and the title was renamed by a moderator to ["Should we burnitiate [corners]?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/10). Note the wording of *burnitiate*, which is important.
- This possible typo was not unnoticed. A comment was added after a minute or so, asking if *burnitiate*, was short to *initiate burnination*. Other "too-chatty" comments followed including *if the comment was not there, I would have edited the title*. The comments were removed as they were not on-topic (perhaps a moderator can edit this post with the exact messages).
- Then, the post was renamed ["Should we cut [corners]?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/13) by a user who *did not know about the deleted comments*. The OP, who was unsure, [rollbacked the edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/14) to the version that was left by the moderator.
- Another user spotted the typo and [fixed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/15), which [was rollbacked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/16) by the OP. This was [to keep the title chosen by the moderator](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28768121#28768121).
- The typo was again [re-fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/17) by another user, and [again rollbacked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/18) for the same reason.
- A third time, another user [re-re-fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/19) the typo. This time, we had heard back from the moderator and [it was indeed a typo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28768152#28768152) that needed to be fixed. As such, this was not rollbacked.
- Then, another user re-introduced a pun by renaming the title ["Should we cut [corners]?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/20).
- Shog9 again stepped in and renamed it ["Should the corners tag be burninated (removed from all questions)?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/21). Note the edit message:

  > It stops being cute and fun when someone has to handle a crapload of flags about it.
- To which a moderator renamed it ["Cutting [corners]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/22), [rollbacked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/295233/23) again.

---

Looking at this history, there are several things we can conclude:

- We have lots of users that are editing the title to a pun without OP's consent. This is not really acceptable: such an edit would be rejected in the queue because it conflicts with author's intent.
- [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) stayed one year without a pun and that hurt nobody. A pun was only edited in after it was featured.
- The edit rollback-war was **not** due to the pun but to a typo, which the OP believed to be intentional from a moderator but, in fact, it was not.

Finally, here are my thoughts about this: I like puns, they're funny and are appreciated. It is true that burninate-requests on Meta generally contain a pun. I see no reason to change that. But, in my opinion, once the post has become featured and is widely visible to **the whole Stack Overflow community**, not just the Meta regulars, puns should be removed because they conflict with the real intent of the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag, which is to draw people in and have constructive feedback on the request itself, and not on the pun. As suggested in the comments by [NathanOliver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver), we can still rename it back to something punny once the post isn't featured anymore.

Comment: Agreed.  If we are going to be featuring the burnation then the title should convey that easily to everyone.  Once the featuring is gone we can always rename it back to something punny.

Comment: *"once stayed one year without a pun and that hurt nobody"* [citation-needed] How do you know that all of Meta is not irreversibly scarred?

Comment: @CodyGray Absolutely agree, it could have hurt someone somewhere! :D .... But seriously speaking, there was no title edits from May 26 15 to Feb 15 16, So it is nearly a year w/o any edits. So we can safely *conclude* that nobody was hurt

Comment: *I see no reason to change that. But, in my opinion, once the post has become featured and is widely visible to the whole Stack Overflow community, not just the Meta regulars, puns should be removed because they conflict with the real intent of the featured tag* - SHouldn't it be more like *Just keep the question as it is. Don't add or remove anything*. If we already have a pun in there, I see no reason to remove it.

Comment: @TheLostMind All constructive edits are still welcomed IMO (fixing typos, grammar, adding numbers, links, etc.). Just like any other questions. From the past burninate-request, mods have changed the title to something generic but that conveys the intent. I do think puns should be removed if there's one, if only to edit it back once the post isn't featured anymore.

Comment: @Tunaki - Should *removal of pun* be considered constructive? :P

Comment: From this series of events, the pun was fine -- the problem is dumb jerks editing to get their own pun in the title and flagging back and forth.

Comment: @tristan That's why I felt important to retrace the whole history there, yes.

Comment: Agree with everything but that editing the title is unacceptable without OP's approval. That's only a problem if things get edited back-and-forth, or the title is changed to something unsuitable, which for featured posts is anything which isn't completely straight-forward. If it had not been featured, there would not have been any ruckus.

Comment: One might argue that in this situation, it would have been better to simply make the title read "burninate" regardless of the moderator's intent as it was such a source of confusion.

Comment: You've destroyed my illusion that “Should we burninate the tag [once]?” actually *was* a pun.

Comment: The "once" request was clearly in the freezer for one year because of the lack of puns. As soon as a pun was added, the burnination got swiftly and effectively sorted out. Thus puns are necessary, .Q.E.D.

Comment: I don't see any value in featuring tag burninations in the first place. Why are we airing our dirty laundry?

Comment: @TylerH That was a widely accepted idea by Shog9. From here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124/1743880

Answer (score 17):

I think that a lot of mess and drama around [edits to the example post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/295233/revisions) happened because of mistake in that "formalised burnination process".

It is unreasonable to expect of editors to know all the rules and limitations of the process. Much simpler way to let them know is to **add hidden markdown note at the top of the post**.

I think that burnination instructions could be improved by requiring moderator who sets [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to also add a note to editors at the top of the post, like this (markdown):

```
<!--
MODERATOR NOTE TO EDITORS:

Please don't edit post title while it has featured tag.

If you ignore this note, moderator will suspend your account for a week.
-->
```

---

<sub>Side note wonder why didn't they put similar note to editors (and edit reviewers!) at the top of the [Zalgo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/828e62e7-5563-4ee5-9e06-5fd3f54b175f/view-source).</sub>

Comment: A week-long suspension is too much IMO. Also, what if the title has a legitimate typo or something, and needs to be edited ?

Comment: @JonasCz I only gave it as a quick example, if folks working on that formalised process are interested in efficiently communicating to editors, it's up to them to tune explanation of what edits are allowed and how to scare off editors who ignore that note

Comment: "If you ignore this note, you are likely to be eaten by a grue."

Comment: Is there a way to hide text in titles?

Comment: @user1803551 no - as far as I know [meta-tag:markdown] is limited only to text. Math sites allow [meta-tag:mathjax] in titles but nothing more (and even this blocks questions with such titles from appearing in [meta-tag:hot-questions] list)

Comment: Oh, I didn't attrubute to you [here](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md)

Answer (score 12):

I'm 100% for the removal of puns in titles.  By organizing a tag-removal/edit action, you're working on one of the more serious, though time-consuming and unrewarding, details of the site.  And just because you're providing work to StackOverflow Corp for free doesn't mean that you're allowed to wear sweatpants or crack jokes while walking around the digital office.  Button up your shirt; this isn't a disco-tech.

Readers would also benefit from keeping in mind that there are now two distinct classes of site users,   **C**ommunity **H**elper, **U**npaid **M**onetizable **P**awns (or **CHUMP**s, for short) and StackOverflow Workers (or **SOW**ers, for short).  Keep in mind that the latter is under no obligation to the former, and that policies meant to manage the former do not apply to the latter.

Although Jeff Atwood stated in the employee handbook ["the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), he was part of the last round of executives, so please keep in mind that there is nothing we can learn from his perspective.  This is a serious business and that needs to seriously monetize -- the culture of the **CHUMP**s must be sacrificed so that future investors may comfortably think of us as a low-cost enterprise documentation provider or place for docile, professional candidates for employment.

Having puns in titles is unprofessional and potentially alienating to new users or those from different cultures.

Can you imagine if a new **CHUMP** starts using the site and doesn't understand what "*burninate*" means?  Although the linked post will bring him or her to *meta.stackoverflow*, a site used by those who have spent enough time on the main site to form opinions about how it's operated, you're expecting him or her to either use a search engine or the site's own searchbox to learn what's meant by ["burninate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag).  This is an unfair expectation that new users spend time reading before participating.

Further, it doesn't matter that StackOverflow is officially an [English-language](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) site.  If your content doesn't read like a Cisco ASA-series firewall manual, it is not suitable for the site.

---

Please note that the above does not apply to the **SOW**ers, their inside jokes, misuse of memes, or the way they conduct themselves when interacting with **CHUMP**s.  If the action of a **SOW**er and/or his/her parent company is logically inconsistent with the above, please keep in mind that StackOverflow is the only popular programming Q&A site, so deal with it and quiet yourself.

*Information in this transmission is intended only for the person(s) to whom it is addressed and may contain privileged and/or confidential information. If you are not the intended recipient, any disclosure, copying or dissemination of the information is unauthorized and you should delete/destroy all copies and notify the sender. No liability is accepted for any unauthorized use of the information contained in this transmission.*

Comment: Can we just rename the sites to ChumpOverflow.com and SowOverflow.com, just to keep everything straight and everyone in their proper place?

Comment: I honestly can't tell if this is serious or satire.

Comment: @MageXy it's satire.  I wanted to write it in a way that it could pass as coming from a humorless, over-the-top oblivious-and-serious person.  There's decidedly a cultural shift happening in which the site is becoming more newbie/"professional" oriented -- further, I was hoping a ridiculous answer would pull in comments about how there's a marked difference between "official" meta posts with memes and a community post being edited to explain common-StackOverflow slang.  Based on the current score of my answer, it was a swing and a miss. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Tristan I wonder how many of the downvotes came from reading the first sentence without reading the remainder of the post. Personally, I give you a +1 just for `If your content doesn't read like a Cisco ASA-series firewall manual, it is not suitable for the site.`

Comment: @reirab Hah, I imagine at least half of the downvotes came from the first sentence or the acronyms (I don't actually hold any strong feelings about puns in titles of meta.stackoverflow posts about tags).  Cheers and I'm glad you found some amusement in my post.

Comment: @tristan Honestly the downvotes were a large part of my confusion. I thought for sure this was satire, but the numerous downvotes implied (to me) that this was a serious post that used off-color humor to mask the controversial opinion "No fun allowed PERIOD". I figured I just missed the train :P

Comment: @MageXy I was ready to downvote after the first paragraph. Changed my mind half way through the second.

Answer (score 7):

As the OP of that question, I feel a few more clarifications are needed in addition to [Tunaki's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316964/1803551) because not all the evidence is left for everyone to see.

Before the post was featured, it had a regular (somewhat accepted) pun and about 10 comments discussing puns with only 1 or 2 comment(s) on-topic. This is the "normal" state in which such posts exist.

The formalized [burnination process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md) that was and is being tested was derived from an answer by Shog9, which asks for a *real* on-topic discussion. As such, the post is brought to an appropriate state for such a discussion, which includes removing all off-topic comments and editing the title.

The supervising moderator removed more than 15 comments and posted their own comment asking users to stop off-topic pun discussion as it generates noise. That comment was generally ignored and off-topic comments continued, which had to be cleaned periodically. As stated in [a comment by Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316947/keep-the-love-of-puns-burninating-in-our-hearts/316970#comment309197_316947),

> I had asked if the typo was deliberate in a comment below the post. The comment was deleted and the title kept. It implied that the title was not a typo. There were further comments stating something like Thanks to the comment, else I would have fixed the typo. The rollback started only after the comments there were deleted to keep them on-topic.

The title that was chosen by the moderator included the word *burnitiate*, which was believed to be *burninate* + *initiate*. This was discussed in the SOCVR room and indeed was a source of confusion. The process [was edited](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/commit/2348e3e434f27cb67553845f23d146754e4d5f4c) to instruct using that title. Only after the confusion was lifted by the moderator did the title settle properly and I had stopped the rollbacks.

Eventually Shog came, edited the title to its final form, and apparently re-obliterated the comments section (many casualties), leaving only [one man standing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295233/should-the-corners-tag-be-burninated-removed-from-all-questions#comment309437_295233).

**To conclude:**

- I have nothing against using puns - I used one myself.
- The rollbacks and comments section cleaning requests were not because I liked or disliked something - they were in accordance with the process and the moderators.
- I don't blame anyone for typos and misunderstandings. My only complaint is towards the users who ignored the clearly-written process and moderators' requests.

**My answer to the question:**

While the post is [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), and after it is cleaned, we *must* restrain ourselves from off-topic discussion because after the post is finished being featured we actually need to read the on-topic parts and arrive at a course of action. After one has been decided, I don't see a problem with returning to off-topic stuff.

That includes the title - while the post is featured, it needs to be presented formally, cleanly, and clearly for *everyone* (not just regulars on meta).

Remember that a post is [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) for only 24 hours. That isn't asking for a lot.

Comment: it would help if your rollbacks included edit summary ([see here how to do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41954/165773)) that would explain that it's to follow formalized burnination process

Comment: @gnat Hmmm, true, didn't think of that one. However, I did edit in an emphasized paragraph on top of my question asking for this, with links to the process and to the chat room for clarifications (which, admittedly, we had none for some time).

Comment: About noisy comments for title suggestions, this question might be good example. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314615/cut-down-on-the-trimming And I still don't know what happened to that request.

Comment: @Lafexlos Oh, corners had a much larger discussion on puns than that one :)

Comment: Yeah, I know but that one at least had rare constructive comments aswell. This one is just about titles and OPs comments shows he doesn't like them at all.

Comment: @Lafexlos As I mentioned in the answer, corners did have 1 or 2 constructive comments. Everything was wiped eventually because of the kerfuffle. If you are talking about the OP of corners, then I am him.

Comment: Was talking about the one I linked. Anyhow, was only trying to show another example that irritated me eventhough I _might_ be the one who triggered it.

Comment: FYI: "burnination process" link is a 404.

Comment: @Kevin Edited, thanks. It's still in the workings so things change.

Answer (score 1):

## Extremes to avoid

- Disallowing all puns, for instance by a [standard question format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317072/1739000).
- Edit wars (for any reason).
- Insisting on puns across the board is just as bad as the first extreme.

## Proposal

Short and sweet, the **OP of the burninate request gets to decide** whether it is punny or not.

Sure, if there are misspellings in the title, fix them, but don't mess with their puns (or with their seriousness). This is still a community-led site and if we are going to let the fact that there is a jobs tab on this site dampen the mood on all the other tabs, we have lost the lovely community we once had. Also, please note that I can immediately spot burninate requests based on the fact that they have [brackets] and a pun, so standardized formats are unnecessary.

*You may optionally allow suggesting a pun if it is an amazing pun and the OP didn't think of it.*

Comment: ["Put this tag out of \[service\]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361187/burninate-the-service-tag-this-time) :P I am in two minds about those endless comments with 'better' punny titles. There are times they get more attention than the target. Sometimes they are pretty funny. Except when they are not.

Comment: @usr2564301, agreed. that's why I made that part of my suggestion optional.

Answer (score -11):

I'm in favour of fixed format and unambiguous titles, such as:

> Burninate [tag]

Or perhaps even something clearer to new users, such as:

> Remove the [tag] tag

The puns are mildly funny sometimes and I generally correctly assume `"... [...] ..."` titles are about burnination, so for me personally it's not such a big deal one way or the other (apart from my OCD).

However, what about newer users or users that simply haven't noticed the burnination title format pattern? They may be misled into clicking on these questions they have no interest in, or not clicking on a question about a tag they're very much invested in (because they don't know the post is about getting rid of it). So basically there could be frustration and views/votes based on the quality of the title rather than the content of the post, neither of which are good IMO.

Not to mention that humour often has the risk of irritating, offending or alienating. AFAIK the official policy is that humour should be kept off the main site, but is generally acceptable / tolerated on Meta. So allowing humour for Meta post titles that are intended to be featured at some point seems to go against this policy. I see some suggestions for back and forth editing, but that seems like creating unnecessary work.

Answer (score -16):

There appear to be two concerns here:

- punny titles are less informative and more confusing

  - puns are (much) less tolerable to be *present* where the need to bring the point across is critical
- the conflict with author's intent

  - puns should only be *introduced* if the question's author(s) intend it to be that way

---

Corollaries:

- It is acceptable for a moderator to edit the title when tagging a Q&A [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) if they strongly feel the original one won't do the job in this position
- Introducing puns - suggested or otherwise - is, in the general case, a controversial edit, and thus shall be handled like any other controversial edit (i.e. not made arbitrarily but discussed and checked against the wishes of those "in charge" of the question<sup>1</sup>).

<sup>1</sup><sub>Who and in what precedence is in charge of a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)[burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) question warrants a separate discussion</sub>

Comment: Re: Intent. Do you mean "only if the author intended it originally" or "only if they're OK with it"? Those are two rather different statements.

Comment: I don't really see why author's intent is relevant here. Just because you couldn't come up with a clever pun doesn't mean that the rest of us should suffer. Someone can help a bro out.

Comment: I hope the formulations are clearer now. The point is - do not go against the author's _intent_ - just like with any other edit.