# I don't want to [badge]r you, but I think this tag needs burnination

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I came across a tag called [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/badge). Is a piece of functionality like this a suitable topic for a tag?

## Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

At least it's unambiguous.

## Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It's more about building web sites or smartphone devices, rather than programming, but it's not too big a problem.

## Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

That's my main concern about the tag.

## Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I think so.

Comment: i'm suprised theres not badge.js.

Comment: While it's on some very high visibility questions (dozens of up votes, tens of thousands of views) every one of the top 20ish questions I looked at appeared to be using it as a meta-tag, for a variety of unrelated platforms.  BURN IT WITH FIRE!

Comment: [I thought puns we're banned now (in general everywhere for everything)...?!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: [Tl;Dr it turns out no](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316947/keep-the-love-of-puns-burninating-in-our-hearts)...which is fine.. :)

Comment: I want a gold badge in... badge. A gold badge badge. Do I have to be an expert at badges for that? Jon Skeet?

Comment: I'm not a mobile dev but the first page of results seems to pretty clearly indicate that this is the term of art for **the little number on an app's home screen icon**. Not sure what the problem is with having a tag for that; presumably we're OK with [tag:toolbar], [tag:favicon], etc etc

Comment: I think the tag excerpt stinks (shouldn't we emphasize the technical aspects, i.e. dynamic content, rather than the intended purpose -- developers seem very bad at assessing what information is important to a user to begin with) but the tag is ok.

Comment: just taking place in case Jon Skeet comes to reply Lundin

Comment: I don't want to go against the grain but I thought the tag description was fairly clear and that I could be useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I oppose burninating the tag, as there's a specific UI component named the "badge": It's the oval on top of a mobile icon or in an HTML component indicating a number of relevant items, such as unread messages. Instead, migrate or close questions that belong(ed) on Meta and remove it from inappropriate questions.

[image: badge on iOS]
[image: Twitter Bootstrap documentation example]
[image: badges on Stack Overflow!]

Comment: So, a tag for a very common and very disparate button that has many thousands ways to get... excellent.

Comment: @Braiam As noted, there are tags for a wide variety of UI elements.

Comment: That doesn't mean that they are good tag either...

Comment: I agree with this answer -- clean out the junk questions but the badge itself is good