# Requesting [immediate] burnination

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I recently came across the [immediate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immediate) tag, and thought I'd do my first burnination request.

This tag has 55 questions, and its description is:

> This tag is ambiguous. Do not use it. See info link for alternatives.

Questions range from using `Execute Immediate` in some RDBMSes, to the Immediate window in the VBA editor, to Immediate mode in some IDEs, to Immediate data types, to real-time data processing.

Let's go through the criteria:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It's usually somewhat descriptive, but totally ambiguous

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Depending on the context, but mostly, again, ambiguous.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not in my opinion, differs per post

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Not at all. An Immediate data type has little to do with the Immediate window in the VBA editor

Comment: Haha, you made a punny!

Comment: This tag has no [immediate] use that I can think of, I say we burn it.

Comment: I always read `burninate` as `BURN - E - ATE` until one day I saw the extra `n` in there.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ So you weren't familiar with Trogdor the Burninator?

Comment: @MrLister Can't say I was, no...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316975/1016716

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the common theme of needing their program to completele immediately, there are a few different posts here:

- Related to the `execute_immediate` command in Oracle DBMS or in PLSQL, which had to be tagged [execute-immediate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute-immediate).
- The ones which were related to the immediate window in VBA, which had to be tagged [immediate-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immediate-window).
- JSF immediate attribute, which had to be tagged [immediate-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immediate-attribute).
- Immediate operands in assembly code, which had to be tagged [immediate-operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immediate-operand).
- Immediate mode in OpenGL, which had to be tagged [immediate-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immediate-mode).
- [One post about OpenLayers immediate property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177861/openlayers-2-immediate-measurement) where the tag was not required.

I closed the off-topic posts, retagged the salvagable posts and deleted the unsalvagable ones. [immediate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immediate) has been *burninated*.

[image]

Comment: I'd just like to say that I'm glad Trogdor is still alive and well somewhere on the internet 15 years later.