# Why do some burninate requests with over 20 votes not get featured?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

*This question is about deviations from the normal burninate process. To review the normal process, see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). A changed version has been posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323121/evaluation-of-socvrs-burnination-process), but the 20 votes lead to featured tag stays the same*

Recently, in a [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356817/can-you-flag-for-moderator-attention-to-ask-for-a-community-manager-to-disappea), it came up that some burninate requests, while achieving the needed 20 votes for featuring, never got [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), and just  disappear into the void.

In the information about the process, there's nothing I can find about this.

Can someone please clarify the process, and explain why some requests with over 20 votes just never get to [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)?

For this discussion, I dug up some old questions as examples:

- [Watson wants to get rid of [ibm]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348131/watson-wants-to-get-rid-of-ibm) (105 votes, posted 2017-04-19)
- [Requesting [immediate] burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355639/requesting-immediate-burnination) (62 votes, posted 2017-08-25)
- [We should not [use] this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342178/we-should-not-use-this) (61 votes, posted 2017-01-24)

Comment: If no-one cares to flag it, nothing will happen.

Comment: @rene do you mean they all need to get flagged for moderator attention as soon as they hit the 20 vote limit? Because that isn't stated in the posts about the process.

Comment: 194 pending requests with more than 20 votes: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bburninate-request%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+score%3A20+is%3Aq

Comment: @Cœur that's quite the backlog. At one per week, if none are added, that's a little under 4 years of burninating to do (3.72 years).

Comment: Here is [another such question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343030/4284627) (by me).

Comment: @Cœur we actually feature posts which have more than 50 questions. It brings down the number of questions to around 90. (So that's 2 years of work)

Comment: Almost a year later ... the 3 examples are all [featured]. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The process is ***entirely manual***.

A moderator has to take the time to look at the eligible burninate requests (or handle a flag<sup>*</sup>), pick one of the eligible ones to action, and then kick it off by following the steps described in [the standard process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071), including making it [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) for a while.

Bhargav was handling a lot of these, but he's been away from the keyboard a lot over the last couple of weeks for reasons. Since I was elected, I've actioned a couple of these as well, and have every intention of continuing to do so.

But even if we handle one per week, it'll still take a while to get through them all, considering how fast they roll in and how large the backlog is. That's why I try to pick the most highly upvoted ones, which are the least controversial, the easiest, and the ones where the tag is probably causing the most harm and thus doing it will have the biggest positive impact.

And handling one per week is pretty much the *fastest* possible rate. You need to leave it featured for at least a couple of days to give everyone a reasonable chance to see it *and* sleep, and then it takes the community a while to actually *do the burnination* (exactly how long depends on the number of questions with the affected tag, of course).

Finally, there's been an uncharacteristically high level of "meta" activity lately, it seems, so it's hard to find a good time to edge in a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) burnination for the community to consider. Several weeks ago, we were featuring and focusing on the sunsetting of Documentation, and none of the moderators really thought it made sense for burnination to compete with that. Right now, although [we just finished up burninating the [research] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323081/we-have-stopped-doing-research), I've been reluctant to kick off another one, given the large amount of meta activity stemming from the roll-out of the new topbar to the other SE sites and our amazing new ability to compare our salaries. Also, the community-led process of removing links to Documentation is still on-going. If you want to participate in improving the site, this would be a good way to do it.

__
<sub>* Yes, users can flag burnination requests that have met the official criteria and that they really want to see get actioned. But...you really don't need to, and the flag may well be declined. It just creates a backlog of Meta flags that nobody can effectively handle and mess up our stats. ;-) It's just as easy, if not easier, for one of us to look through [all of the pending burnination requests, sorting by vote, and excluding the ones that have already been assigned a status (completed, declined, whatever)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+-status-completed+-status-declined). The backlog of requests is already maintained by Meta's tag system; we don't really need to duplicate it in the flag queue.</sub>

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth SOCVR used a SEDE query http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/493425/burninate-priority-list to determine the order in which we would request featuring and handle the burnination.  It now is more loosely governed by the mods or by some of the regulars in SOCVR.  Keep in mind that a lot of folks love to bring up the burnination request but don't seem to fancy participating in the actual busy work. Maybe we should mention that in the process: *don't bother to post a request if you're not willing to participate in the clean-up* ...

Comment: Yes, [the backlog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+-status-completed+-status-declined) *does* get processed, @Erik. That's what we've been doing. [entry] and [research] were both in the backlog, and they're the last two we did. You can flag if you want, but no real reason. I updated my answer with details. I don't know how to make it much more clear than I already did. There are inherent limits on the speed of the process, then there are external factors, and finally there are human factors. Once you solve all of those, then we'll really be able to move fast!

Comment: `You need to leave it featured for at least a couple of days to give everyone a reasonable chance to see it` The current guidelines say it should be featured for one day.  Perhaps they should be edited if the actual plan is to leave them featured for several days.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the information, this makes it really clear to me. Only was bringing these up since in the discussion I referred to, someone said they didn't all get featured, and I couldn't find a source that disputed that and allowed for those old questions not to get featured. I certainly am grateful for the good work you and the other mods and regulars are doing (and will try to help burninating more)!

Comment: Okay, I completely rewrote [the burnination procedure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071) to match what I've been doing, which is not only what I feel strongly about, but that I have evidence has been working well. I know it looks like I changed everything, but I really didn't. The original process is still recognizably intact; I just changed a lot of the wording and clarified the presentation. Hopefully that'll help a bit. (cc @Erik)

Comment: You could feature two at a time if the weather is nice.

Comment: @Servy Looks like when we were crafting it earlier this year/late last year we remembered to say the [meta-tag:status-review] should take *at least* one day, but forgot to give the same consideration to the [meta-tag:featured] step. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: TL;DR: Limited community resources.