# No Shirt, No Shoes, No [service]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There is still the [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) tag.

It has **23,024 questions**

It usually contains questions about

- [android-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-service) ([9,137](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service+android) with [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android))
- [windows-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-service) ([2,055](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service+windows) with [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) and [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows))
- [web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-services) ([552](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service+web) with [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) and [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web))

I believe we should retag that questions with the more specific one, but with that large number of questions I believe it is not really doable by hand.

[There are 10,370 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service+-android+-windows+-web+-soap+-rest+-web-services+-windows-services+-winapi) tagged [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) not [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) not [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) not [soap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soap) not [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest) not [web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-services) not [windows-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-services) not [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi)

I believe that the other questions could be retagged en-masse:

- [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) -> [android-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-service)
- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) or [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) -> [windows-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-services)
- [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web), [soap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soap) or [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest) -> [web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-services)

There is also the highly related tag [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), which looks like it could map to [wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf), although some of the questions are about [windows-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-services).

Because some people asked me to address the burnination requirements, here they are:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** Nope. **And is it unambiguous?** Haha. Nope.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** What concept? "Something running without user interaction"? In that case we need a [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** Nope.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** Read above. Hint: Nope.

Comment: Note: this is a repost of the old question on [meta.se]: [Retag all service questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208161/retag-all-service-questions). It was once posted here, then moved to [meta.se], closed there for being off-topic.

Comment: Hmm, 18k questions would take a lot of effort, if we follow the normal burnination process. [Godaddy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817) had nearly 2k, and I remember how the normal users felt the heat while burning. [Apple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348017/) started with 3k,  and did take more than 3 months to complete (even there, we just focused on the real bad questions and retagged few of them). Here, we're speaking about 6 times the magnitude of that. Perhaps we need a special burn process for these huge tags.

Comment: @Bhargav sorry, you can have all the special processes you want, without the increase in magnitude of reviewers (which is unlikely), or a systematic change in the efficacy of reviews (i.e. somehow reducing the number of reviews required per question to achieve the desired result), it just ain't gonna happen. Even if we ignore the questions that already have a corresponding *-service tag (those would be safe to bulk-remove the tag from), that only brings it down to [17,118](https://goo.gl/JS6ZEX) questions. ...

Comment: ... Even if we remove all of the tags that the OP here has accounted for as well as all possible *service* tags, we're still left with [7,351](https://goo.gl/2MXHg1), meaning that the number of questions that this request does not take into account is ~1.5 times the number of questions in the Apple burnination. If this request were to achieve consensus, the only option I see that would be any kind of possible would be to just skip to the last step and remove the tag from all questions, then review the untagged questions.

Comment: That would also be almost the exact same process that the [internet burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287423/4639281) followed (i.e. shog just burned it all and asked meta to review the orphans).

Comment: Yeah, @Tiny, by a "special burn" process, I did not mean changing the entire process of burnination, but just a change the step where users actually vote to close, while cleaning the tag. I've discussed this with Shog in the mod room, way back in Feb, this year (shortly after a tag burnination). He did mention about skipping the step where we close the questions, and stick to just retagging the questions, which were worthy and then pulling in the CMs for the final step (step 5). This hasn't been mentioned clearly in the burn process.

Comment: @TinyGiant actually, Shog did review some of these questions, found some that he deleted outright, and he found it so unproductive and the tag so worthless that he just decided to nuke it from orbit.

Comment: OP: "the the" is really bothering me and I can't edit.

Comment: Note that there is also [tag:angular-services].

Comment: “This tag should be out of [service]”?

Comment: I see that the [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) tag has been used numerous times over just the last day. Note that there is a [wiki page for the service tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/service/info). When there is a Meta consensus that a tag should be burninated, at what point does the community decide to place a cautionary statement in the tag's wiki page that the tag should no longer be used?

Comment: @Braiam I was oversimplifying, not blind.

Comment: Are we allowed to use Selenium? :)

Comment: Also, can you address the usual burnination requirements?

Comment: The [service] in this place is terrible!

Comment: No shirt, no shoes, no [service]!

Comment: We need the [service] of Trogdor the Burninator.

Comment: The last time I posted this request, it had 9,333 questions. I suggest that we at least ban the use of this tag, so it can't be applied to new questions.

Comment: **[What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)**. Please do not start removing the tag during the "proposal" or "featuring" phases! Do not edit the title to indicate that this burnination is in progress, as it has not yet received consensus. cc@JohannesKuhn

Comment: Read your link again, it's forbidden to change the title when the question is featured (step 2). We are still in step 1.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you are allowed to pun, you are not allowed to indicate that the burnination is underway when it has yet to reach consensus. That would be disingenuously tricking users into participating in burninating a tag prior to consensus, which would be a bad thing. Keep in mind that due to the multiple rollbacks, an automatic flag will have been raised for a moderator to review the situation.